# Question related to Blender measure tool

Tags: modeling, mesh, measurement

Newbie question, I'm afraid ...

When enabling vertex snapping, in Solid Display, the Measure tool works ok. I can LMB snap to a start vertex and drag to an end vertex, release mouse button and the correct length will be displayed.

However, changing to *Wireframe mode* (no X-ray), when using the Measure tool, the tool "appears" to behave correctly (same APPARENT behaviour as in Solid mode, *looks* like it is snapping ok) but the start vertex will NOT be snapped to, only the end vertex will.

(I cannot see any reason that measuring should behave different in these two modes?)

What am I missing??

If I *turn off global* snapping, and instead use CTRL (when using the Measure tool) to activate snapping, then apparently it again *appears* to snap to the first and last selected vertex. But - in fact - the same problem is present, only the end vertex is snapped to. The start vertex is never snapped to. I am totally confused by this...

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug, that I am able to reproduce. Please, consider reporting it by going to *Help -> Report A Bug*, make sure to fill in all required information.

Comment: Reported. This problem seems to exist in Blender 3.3.4 LTS, 3.4.1 and as well the experimental 3.6.0.